# Sum by unique variable pairs

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking for a way to cleanly sum the unique pairings of my two variables, preferably, in `data.table`.

Here's my data:

```
 > x_base
    State SA2 Population_SA2
 1:     A   x            304
 2:     A   x            304
 3:     A   y             79
 4:     A   y             79
 5:     A   y             79
 6:     B   z            961
 7:     B   z            961
 8:     B   z            961
 9:     B   z            961
10:     B   w             90
11:     B   w             90
12:     B   u            550
13:     C   v            113
14:     C   v            113
15:     C   t            425
16:     C   t            425
17:     C   t            425
```

What I want to do is to calculate the sum of `Population_SA2` by `State`. However, I've got multiple entries for each `State` and `SA2` pair, for instance I've got two pairs of `State == A & SA2 == x`, but when i sum over `Population_SA2`, it would be incorrect to count 304 twice, likewise it would be incorrect to count 79 three times. The population for `State` A should be 383 (304 + 79).

Here's my current solution:

1) Find the unique `State` and `SA2` pairs:

```
> x_unique <- unique(x_base)
> x_unique
   State SA2 Population_SA2
1:     A   x            304
2:     A   y             79
3:     B   z            961
4:     B   w             90
5:     B   u            550
6:     C   v            113
7:     C   t            425
```

2) Sum `Population_SA2` by `State`:

```
> x_unique <- x_unique[,.(sum_by_state = sum(Population_SA2)), by = State]
> x_unique
   State sum_by_state
1:     A          383
2:     B         1601
3:     C          538
```

3) Merge back onto the initial `data.table`:

```
> x_final <- merge(x_base, x_unique[,.(State,sum_by_state)], by = "State")
> x_final
    State SA2 Population_SA2 sum_by_state
 1:     A   x            304          383
 2:     A   x            304          383
 3:     A   y             79          383
 4:     A   y             79          383
 5:     A   y             79          383
 6:     B   z            961         1601
 7:     B   z            961         1601
 8:     B   z            961         1601
 9:     B   z            961         1601
10:     B   w             90         1601
11:     B   w             90         1601
12:     B   u            550         1601
13:     C   v            113          538
14:     C   v            113          538
15:     C   t            425          538
16:     C   t            425          538
17:     C   t            425          538
```

I'd be really keen to know if this can be done in a cleaner, more concise way, where I don't have to create any intermediate objects.

Much appreciated!

Not sure if necessary, but here's a `dput()`

```
structure(list(State = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), SA2 = c("x", "x", 
"y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "w", "w", "u", "v", "v", "t", 
"t", "t"), Population_SA2 = c(304L, 304L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 961L, 
961L, 961L, 961L, 90L, 90L, 550L, 113L, 113L, 425L, 425L, 425L
)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000121ef0>)
```

Comment: If you're interested in a cleaner way of handling such data, I'd suggest using multiple normalized/tidy tables (rather than a single one with a complicated structure leading to repeated/redundant values). Hadley's paper is a good guide: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `data.table` solution is

```
x_base[, sum_by_state := sum(Population_SA2[!duplicated(SA2)]), by = State]
x_base
#     State SA2 Population_SA2 sum_by_state
#  1:     A   x            304          383
#  2:     A   x            304          383
#  3:     A   y             79          383
#  4:     A   y             79          383
#  5:     A   y             79          383
#  6:     B   z            961         1601
#  7:     B   z            961         1601
#  8:     B   z            961         1601
#  9:     B   z            961         1601
# 10:     B   w             90         1601
# 11:     B   w             90         1601
# 12:     B   u            550         1601
# 13:     C   v            113          538
# 14:     C   v            113          538
# 15:     C   t            425          538
# 16:     C   t            425          538
# 17:     C   t            425          538
```

A `dplyr`-solution would be:

```
library(dplyr)

x_base %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  mutate(sum_by_state = sum(Population_SA2[!duplicated(SA2)]))

# A tibble: 17 x 4
# Groups:   State [3]
#    State SA2   Population_SA2 sum_by_state
#    <chr> <chr>          <int>        <int>
# 1  A     x                304          383
# 2  A     x                304          383
# 3  A     y                 79          383
# 4  A     y                 79          383
# 5  A     y                 79          383
# 6  B     z                961         1601
# 7  B     z                961         1601
# 8  B     z                961         1601
# 9  B     z                961         1601
# 10 B     w                 90         1601
# 11 B     w                 90         1601
# 12 B     u                550         1601
# 13 C     v                113          538
# 14 C     v                113          538
# 15 C     t                425          538
# 16 C     t                425          538
# 17 C     t                425          538
```